# Webpack+SemanticUI+React: process is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have found numerous posts about the Webpack error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

most of which suggest adding a plugin to the `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [ 
  // ...
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
      }
  }),
  // ...
]
```

however this does not seem to do the trick in my case.

To make things easy, I have created [a repo](https://github.com/sheljohn/minimal-semantic-react) with the bare minimum to setup [SemanticUI-React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) with Webpack, which should be straightforward to navigate. My config in `webpack.config.js` is heavily inspired from this [recent tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/) which seems to have a lot of positive comments.

To reproduce the error, just clone the repo on your machine (I use `yarn`, but this should work with `npm` too):

```
git clone https://github.com/sheljohn/minimal-semantic-react
cd minimal-semantic-react/
yarn install
yarn run serve
```

which opens at `localhost:3000`, and the error can be seen in the developer console.

As far as I understand, it seems that when React loads, it is looking to determine whether production or development mode is set, using the variable `process.env.NODE_ENV`, which is undefined in the browser.

This might be related to the `target` field in the Webpack config (set to `web` by default); but since React is loaded from CDN, prior to the bundle, I guess it doesn't know about what WebPack is doing, which makes me perplex as to why adding a plugin in the config would change anything...

Hence my question: **is it possible to use semantic-ui-react by declaring the big libs (React, ReactDOM, semantic) as externals?** Everything works fine if I bundle them, but the bundle ends up around 4MB, which is quite big.

---

### Additional Details

Error as seen in Chrome (OSX High Sierra, v66.0.3359.181, dev console):

```
react.development.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react.development.js:14
(anonymous) @ react.development.js:14
```

and code excerpt at line 14:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
```

---

File `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const publicFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.jsx",
  target: "web",
  output: {
    path: publicFolder,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: publicFolder,
    port: 3000
  },
  externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery',
    'lodash': '_',
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'semantic-ui-react': 'semantic-ui-react'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [ 
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

---

File `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally solved this:

- **Mistake #1**: I was using `cjs` versions of the React libs from cdnjs, when I should have been using `umd` instead. Although UMD style is ugly, it seems to work fine within browsers, whereas CommonJS uses `require` for example. See [this post](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/) for a comparison of AMD / CommonJS / UMD.
- **Mistake #2**: in `webpack.config.js`, the "name" for the external `semantic-ui-react` should be `semanticUIReact` (case sensitive). This is what is defined in the `window` global when the script is loaded from the CDN (e.g. like `jQuery` or `React`).

I updated [**the repository**](https://github.com/sheljohn/minimal-semantic-react) with these fixes, and you should be able to reproduce that working example on your machine. **This repository contains the bare minimum needed to get SemanticUI, React and Webpack working together.** This would have saved me a lot of time, so hopefully other people get to benefit from that!

Comment: Link to repositories for future reference (June 2018):
[Semantic+React+Webpack](https://github.com/sheljohn/minimal-semantic-react); [Semantic+React+Webpack+Storybook](https://github.com/sheljohn/minimal-semantic-react-storybook).

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works fine if I bundle them, but the bundle ends up around 4MB, which is quite big.

It's because you bundle them in "development" mode. Try using "production" in your script instead, it will be much smaller.
`"build": "webpack --mode production"`

If you bundle everything in production, without specifying external, it will be better for a standalone app.

Comment: Good to know, and it makes sense :) I'm both old and new to the web-dev world, but using CDNs seems to be a no-brainer these days; I get that bundling all dependencies makes it standalone, but I doubt this is a "good" thing to do.

Comment: Well, it's better regarding compatibility of versions. If you pack something developed for React 16 and in a year React 17 comes out and you uses your component with it, it will most surely break.

Comment: CDN links usually include a version; apart from the hassle of maintaining these links manually (which you would have to do with the package file anyway), I don't think this is an issue.